# Block is not entered on a ActiveRecord_Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Ruby and RoR.

I have a class method that looks like this:

```
def self.show_all_expired
  puts "\r\n COUNT: #{self.expired.all.count}\r\n"
  self.expired.all do |s|
    puts "\r\n COUNT: #{s}\r\n"
  end
  puts "\r\nEND\r\n"
end
```

When I run it from the console I get this output:

[image]

As you can see the subscriptions collection is not iterated and the block body is not entered at all. But the count of the query is 31, so there must be records. Why `do` block is not executed?

Comment: becuase `all` does not take a block. You are looking for `all.each` or really just `each`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the docs you can see that [`all`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-all) doesn't expect a block. It just returns the ActiveRecord::Relation scope object.

Instead, you want to use [`each`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Result.html#method-i-each) which calls the given block once for each element in row collection:

```
self.expired.each do |s|
  puts "\r\n Subscription: #{s.inspect}\r\n"
end
```

Or [`find_each`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_each) if you are dealing with a larger number of records.